.NET App is not using OpenSSL Certificate store on Linux Docker Container
I have a .NET 8 (8.0.8) Web API which call external API using RestSharp.
The GET method is not executing because of the error I have:
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

External API successfully responses when I call the same URL in curl from the same docker container, so I assume that all needed certificates are present on the docker image.
I tried to print all the certificates used by the HttpClient/RestSharp during the connection, on my local dev in IDE it works, on Docker container not (I used ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback).
I also tried to bypass the SSL verification by this:
ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true

But I have the same SSL error.
I found in some answer that .NET is not using the same certificates list as the openssl on Linux, but I can't iterate threw these certificates during connection so I don't know what's going on.

If disabling certificate validation does not help then the problem cannot be a failed certificate validation. Also nothing in "connection could not be established, see inner exception" suggests this, since it is only a very generic error.

So what is the inner exception? And it's not clear: are you using client certificates, or is only the server certificate relevant? And please be clear about who is calling who, is it an external machine calling another machine, and the client is in Docker, or the server is in Docker, or are they on the same machine, different containers, etc?

@SteffenUllrich inner exception: Authentication failed, see inner exception. Level 2 inner exception: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.

@Charlieface My web api on docker image run locally on laptop or in Azure Container App is calling external API available on a public .com domain

@reverterez: SSL_ERROR_SSL is a generic error but has usually nothing to do with certificate validation. Depending on what kind of server you access it might be that the server has some anti-bot detection using SSL fingerprinting and will reject your access  by closing the connection during the TLS handshake.

@SteffenUllrich I retrieved the lowest exception message:
error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure

@reverterez: unfortunately handshake failure is similar generic. But you'll likely don't get anything better since this is how SSL error handling works :( . Typical causes of this error are wrong/missing client certificate, not using SNI where server requires it, missing extension the server wants, ... - very broad range. Helpful for debugging would be a packet capture (tcpdump, wireshark) of a successful connection with wget and a failed connection with your app - so that one can compare what is different.

It sounds like there might be a cipher or hash algorithm or TLS version mismatch between client and server (there needs to a common cipher and version between them). A Wireshark/tcpdump trace showing the Client and Server Hellos will tell you if this is the case.

Here are three tcpdump outputs:

My local machine app run in IDE (works): https://pastebin.com/5uhp3ktJ
Docker (curl) (works): https://pastebin.com/9Drf5PXJ
Docker (.net app) (fails): https://pastebin.com/Kq0bNdnM


It was a cipher suit miss match ;) I wrote a final solution in the thread. Thanks guys!

So for those who will have the same problem - it's the cipher suit missmatch between the server (which support only TLS1.2) and the .NET HttpClient. I had to manually set the cipher suit for the HttpClient:
var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler()
    {
        SslOptions =
        {
            CipherSuitesPolicy = new CipherSuitesPolicy(
                new[]
                {
                    TlsCipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
                    TlsCipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                    TlsCipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                    TlsCipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
                })
        }
    };

And then use it with the HttpClient:
using(var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)){...}

More about that issue:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux

You shouldn't need to set these manually from .NET 8, unless your Windows installation is way out of date.

Why? And what should I do?

Because by default all ciphers that are available to the operating system will be offered. All the above code does is limit the list of available ciphers. It's rather strange that doing the above actually helps. But perhaps .NET on Linux is different than Windows in this respect.

Also it looks like from that document you linked that if you specify the ciphers in openssl.cnf config file then they should be used, it's only if they are not that it falls back to the defaults shown.
